# Aligning views in android support Toolbar xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

Using the android support `Toolbar`, I am trying to achieve this layout.

[image]

Essentially, I'm showing a progress bar , aligned to the right of the toolbar, which goes away after loading has finished , replaced with two "A"s.

1- I can Hide the progress bar and show the two "A"s when loading completes as needed

2- I need to get the two "A"s or the progress bar to nicely sit aligned right while at the same time keeping the app name in the center

I have tried various layout containers, but wanted to avoid hardcoding pixel margins if avoidable, and I wanted to prevent unnecessary container nesting.

This is my toolbar xml. The **left arrow**isn't part of the layout, it comes from here :

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

**XML ( this isn't the exact xml which I used to take the screenshot , and is missing the layoutgravity but it wasn't working anyway)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/toolbar_color">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_fontsizewrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_titletextview"
            style="@style/ToolBarText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My APP NAME" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_decreasefont"
            style="@style/ToolBarText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="A"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_increasefont"
            style="@style/ToolBarText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/webclientprogressbar"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Any help appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `LinearLayout`, try using `RelativeLayout`.

**1.** Use `RelativeLayout` as a direct child of `Toolbar`.

**2.** Use attribute `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to your `toolbar_titletextview` to keep it in center position of `Toolbar`.

**3.** Use another `RelativeLayout` as a container of `ProgressBar` and align this `RelativeLayout` to the right of `Toolbar`.

**4.** Align two `TextViews` to the left of `progress_container` with initially `visible` state `GONE`.

If you want to hide `ProgressBar` and show two `TextViews`, then just set visibility GONE to ProgressBar `webclientprogressbar`. The `TextViews` 'A**A**' will automatically replace the position of `Progressbar`.

**Here is the working code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_fontsizewrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_titletextview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="My APP NAME"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/progress_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/webclientprogressbar"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_increasefont"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/progress_container"
            android:text="A"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_decreasefont"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/toolbar_increasefont"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/toolbar_increasefont"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="1.5dp"
            android:text="A"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
webclientprogressbar = VISIBLE, 
toolbar_decreasefont = GONE and toolbar_increasefont = GONE
```

[image]

```
webclientprogressbar = GONE, 
toolbar_decreasefont = VISIBLE and toolbar_increasefont = VISIBLE
```

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: +1 for the steps explained! This mostly works but I can't get the two baselines for the As to align with MY APP NAME (it looks like your image above ). So far no luck trying to fiddle with alignbaseline or alignbottom. The larger A always stays slightly higher than the smaller ( unlike the desired result image i posted) :(

Comment: Its happening due to different font size. Larger font size has almost larger padding that's why capital A stays slightly higher than small A although their baseline is same. To align two textviews, just add bottom padding `android:paddingBottom="1.5dp"` to  your textview `toolbar_decreasefont`. I have updated my answer. try this

Comment: Glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I can suggest you for this layout is to set the "gravity" of your main horizontal "LinearLayout" to "center". After that just paste the view given below before and after the "App Name" textview.

```
<view
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Hope this will work for you!